# Why Magento Shopping Cart show wrong price and sometime not allow to add product?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I'm having a problem with my shopping cart. Few of my customer complain they have shown different in the total sum price. Another problem is they can't Add more then 2 product. Interestingly I'm receiving small amount of order from my website without any problem. But this some customer complain that fact. Even they sent screenshot.

My question is am i missing anything or any one have this kind of problem?

Comment: Most probably the problem is refers to some javascript error. It will be very helpful if you: 1. upload here customer screenshot. 2. try to reproduce the issue yourself and then tell us how you've done it 3. provide us your site url to let us look at your checkout.

Comment: Hi  zhartaunik, You can check the screenshot from [here](http://jrdecal.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/JRDECAL1.jpg). and this is my website http://jrdecal.com.